# How to connect Arduino due to GPS module?

Tags: arduino, gps, arduino-due, software-serial

I am working on an Arduino project, I am beginner with Arduino, so I started to get code from the Internet and trying to study and understand it,

https://www.hackster.io/bigboystoys13/diymall-gprs-gps-sim5320e-3g-module-at-commands-d1cbfe

I tried to upload this code to the **Due** board, so it appears an error with the software serial library, here is the error:

```
    Arduino: 1.8.4 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Due (Programming Port)"

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp:125:2: error: #error This version of SoftwareSerial supports only 20, 16 and 8MHz processors

 #error This version of SoftwareSerial supports only 20, 16 and 8MHz processors

  ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp: In member function 'bool SoftwareSerial::listen()':

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp:181:23: error: 'SREG' was not declared in this scope

     uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;

                       ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp:182:9: error: 'cli' was not declared in this scope

     cli();

         ^

In file included from C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\sam\1.6.11\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:201:0,

                 from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp:43:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp: In member function 'void SoftwareSerial::setTX(uint8_t)':

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\sam\1.6.11\variants\arduino_due_x/variant.h:63:65: error: invalid conversion from 'Pio*' to 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' [-fpermissive]

 #define digitalPinToPort(P)        ( g_APinDescription[P].pPort )

                                                                 ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp:357:18: note: in expansion of macro 'digitalPinToPort'

   uint8_t port = digitalPinToPort(tx);

                  ^

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\sam\1.6.11\variants\arduino_due_x/variant.h:66:44: error: base operand of '->' is not a pointer

 #define portOutputRegister(port)   ( &(port->PIO_ODSR) )

                                            ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp:358:27: note: in expansion of macro 'portOutputRegister'

   _transmitPortRegister = portOutputRegister(port);

                           ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp: In member function 'void SoftwareSerial::setRX(uint8_t)':

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\sam\1.6.11\variants\arduino_due_x/variant.h:63:65: error: invalid conversion from 'Pio*' to 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' [-fpermissive]

 #define digitalPinToPort(P)        ( g_APinDescription[P].pPort )

                                                                 ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp:368:18: note: in expansion of macro 'digitalPinToPort'

   uint8_t port = digitalPinToPort(rx);

                  ^

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\sam\1.6.11\variants\arduino_due_x/variant.h:67:44: error: base operand of '->' is not a pointer

 #define portInputRegister(port)    ( &(port->PIO_PDSR) )

                                            ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp:369:26: note: in expansion of macro 'portInputRegister'

   _receivePortRegister = portInputRegister(port);

                          ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp: In member function 'void SoftwareSerial::begin(long int)':

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp:380:31: error: 'table' was not declared in this scope

   for (unsigned i=0; i<sizeof(table)/sizeof(table[0]); ++i)

                               ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp:396:38: error: 'digitalPinToPCICR' was not declared in this scope

     if (digitalPinToPCICR(_receivePin))

                                      ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp:398:78: error: 'digitalPinToPCICRbit' was not declared in this scope

       *digitalPinToPCICR(_receivePin) |= _BV(digitalPinToPCICRbit(_receivePin));

                                                                              ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp:398:79: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope

       *digitalPinToPCICR(_receivePin) |= _BV(digitalPinToPCICRbit(_receivePin));

                                                                               ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp:399:37: error: 'digitalPinToPCMSK' was not declared in this scope

       *digitalPinToPCMSK(_receivePin) |= _BV(digitalPinToPCMSKbit(_receivePin));

                                     ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp:399:78: error: 'digitalPinToPCMSKbit' was not declared in this scope

       *digitalPinToPCMSK(_receivePin) |= _BV(digitalPinToPCMSKbit(_receivePin));

                                                                              ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp: In member function 'void SoftwareSerial::end()':

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp:414:36: error: 'digitalPinToPCMSK' was not declared in this scope

   if (digitalPinToPCMSK(_receivePin))

                                    ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp:415:77: error: 'digitalPinToPCMSKbit' was not declared in this scope

     *digitalPinToPCMSK(_receivePin) &= ~_BV(digitalPinToPCMSKbit(_receivePin));

                                                                             ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp:415:78: error: '_BV' was not declared in this scope

     *digitalPinToPCMSK(_receivePin) &= ~_BV(digitalPinToPCMSKbit(_receivePin));

                                                                              ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp: In member function 'virtual size_t SoftwareSerial::write(uint8_t)':

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp:450:21: error: 'SREG' was not declared in this scope

   uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;

                     ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp:451:7: error: 'cli' was not declared in this scope

   cli();  // turn off interrupts for a clean txmit

       ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp:455:26: error: 'XMIT_START_ADJUSTMENT' was not declared in this scope

   tunedDelay(_tx_delay + XMIT_START_ADJUSTMENT);

                          ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp: In member function 'virtual void SoftwareSerial::flush()':

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp:498:21: error: 'SREG' was not declared in this scope

   uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;

                     ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.cpp:499:7: error: 'cli' was not declared in this scope

   cli();

       ^

exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino Due (Programming Port).

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: It would appear your board (or at least the processor on your board) is incompatible with this software.

Comment: so is there any solution or any other library i can use instead of the version I am usingg

Comment: as i have read on the internet, i found that the arduino due is not compatible with all the GSM shield

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you not select the type of arduino in the arduino IDE.
You'll need to select the entry in the Tools > Board menu that corresponds to your Arduino due or Genuino board or other. Also you need select the port where is connect the arduino.
more info: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoDue

Comment: check this preferences: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M8YXOlBd9xgGYj1L9oe9OfnIsTUb0Dfg/view?usp=sharing